# whiteboard application

Tags: java

i wanted to develop a whiteboard application..i know the basics of java..but have no idea where to start from..so..i'd really appreciate if you could guide me..as in..where do i start from??

Comment: what exactly is a "whiteboard application"?

Comment: I dont think this was worth a downvote, the question seems clear to me.

Comment: **@Lerxst:** Not really. The question is deducible, but that is a far cry from clear. **@Alice:** You presumably mean some kind of internet-mediated collaborative writing/drawing space right? So what are your requirements? Exactly two users or N-fold? Synchronous or asynchronous? And so on. *But wait, there's more!* What *do* you know about what you need? You've tagged it java, so I presume you've at least followed some java tutorial. But do you know anything about network communication in java? Do you know anything about graphical interfaces in java? You've got to help us here...

Comment: I want to develop a shared whiteboard application..but m nt doin it on a very large scale..so 2 users will be fine..synchronous or asynchronous..both will do..and ya..i have studied java swings and also have an idea of socket programming..

Comment: **@Alice:** If you know how to draw the windows and put the text and graphics in place, then you need two things: 1) to know how each instance is going to communicate the desired text/graphics with the other and 2) how to send those messages back and forth. You're unlikely to get a lot of interest in a "Help, I don't even know where to start." type question even if it were reopened. You'd be better off looking for answers to more specific questions (and asking them if they are not already on the site). Try searching on `[java] socket beginner` and see what comes up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advise you to download an existing open-source whiteboard Java project and study the code. For example, look at some of [the existing ones here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/query/#q=java%20whiteboard).

Download a few different ones and look at how they do it, then you'll have a better idea of what's necessary and can come up with how you are going to do yours.

Most likely their implementations will be centered around the following packages: `java.awt.*`, `java.awt.event.*`, `java.awt.geom.*`. You'll probably want to have some kind of Shape class from which you derive other classes representing each shape you want to draw. The drawing will be done in the `paintComponent()` method of the component you'll use to draw (for example a JPanel).

If you plan on making this a shared whiteboard, I'd advise you to focus on getting the painting done first, then worry about distribution. For distributing the app you can look at Sockets, Applets, Corba, RMI, Apache River, Web services, ... The easiest to implement will probably be RMI, and the fastest plain sockets.